# docker-compose: how to connect two projects so they could send requests to each other

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, backend

Let's say, I have two projects: spam-service and eggs-service.

Here is the spam's YAML-file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  spam-db:
    image: postgres:11.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: spam
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  spam-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./config/local/Dockerfile
    container_name: spam-service
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - spam-db
    environment:
      DEBUG: True
      APP_ENV: 'LOCAL_DOCKER'
      BROKER_HOST_NAME: redis-spam
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: spam
      POSTGRES_HOST: spam-db
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:8877:8000'
```

The Egg's service is absolutely identical, just replace 'spam' to 'eggs' and ports are also different. How can I connect these two containerized projects so the could send api requests to each other? And what precisely URL I have to use to send such requests.

I tried something like this but no success:

```
version: '3'

services:
  ...

  spam-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./config/local/Dockerfile
    container_name: spam-service
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - spam-db
    environment:
      ...
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:8877:8000'
    networks: &networks
      - local-network

networks:
  local-network:
    external: true
```

`POST http://spam-service:8877/api/v1/cache/`

[2024-03-20 22:04:32,730: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-4] Error on send data to spam_cachenotok: HTTPConnectionPool(host='spam-service', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/cache/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x760d642e54c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')), url: http://spam-service:8001/api/v1/cache/, data: {'blah': 'blah'}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both need to be on the same Compose network.  Since the second one explicitly configures an external network, in the first file you can configure the `default` network to be the same network.  Then you can use the Compose service names `spam-service` and `eggs-service` as host names to call from one to the other.